# The configuration section 'customErrors' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have uploaded my webpage to a server.

My webpage is working  fine in the local system. But when I upload it to the server it is showing the error

> The configuration section 'customErrors' cannot be read because it is
>   missing a section declaration.

I have tried all the possibility but still i am getting the above error. Can anyone suggest what should I change in my config file to resolve the issue?

My Webconfig File:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="neatUpload" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.ConfigSectionHandler, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" allowLocation="true" />
        <sectionGroup name="modulesSection">
            <section name="rewriteModule" type="RewriteModule.RewriteModuleSectionHandler, RewriteModule" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <!-- <customErrors mode="ON" /> -->
    <!--  <customErrors mode="Off" />  -->
    <customErrors mode="ON" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.html">
         <!--   <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" /> -->
    </customErrors>
    <modulesSection>
        <rewriteModule>
            <rewriteOn>true</rewriteOn>
            <rewriteRules>
            <rule source="http://[^/]*/*(\w+[&amp;-]*\w+)/*((\w+[&amp;-]*\w+)(\s)*)*/*((\w+[&amp;-]*\w+)(\s)*)*$" destination="landPage.aspx?CampaginName=$1&amp;SubDomain=$2&amp;UserName=$3&amp;PageName=$4" />
            <!-- <rule source=".*" destination="landPage.aspx?CampaginName=$1&amp;UserName=$2"/>-->
            </rewriteRules>
        </rewriteModule>
    </modulesSection>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`<CustomErrors>` goes under `<system.web>`  You have yours under `<configuration>` directly.  That is, the parent element of your customErrors tag is configuration, which is incorrect.   Checking [MSDN on customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) will show you the correct structure to add it to your config file.

```
<configuration>
    <!-- your other stuff -->
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="ON" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.html">
             <!--   <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" /> -->
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply. After doing this it is showing "Unrecognized element 'system.web'" error

Comment: I would be willing to bet you have your system.web nested inside another section, or at the top before configSections.  Make sure `<system.web>` comes after your `</modulesSection>`